# Protracor comapare 2 strings arrays

Tags: selenium, testing, jasmine, protractor, frontend

I am using Protractor framework.

The problem is that i have 2 arrays :

```
var a= [ 'Mon. Dec 10, 2018',
  'Mon. Feb 11, 2019',
  'Tue. Feb 12, 2019',
  'Tue. Aug 13, 2019' ]

var b= [ 'MON. DEC 10', 'MON. FEB 11', 'TUE. FEB 12', 'TUE. AUG 13' ]
```

I want to compere to those arrays like:

```
expect(a(index)).toContain(b(index))
```

To check if the first element from first array '**Mon. Dec 10, 2018**' contains the first element from the second array '**MON. DEC 10**' and so on.

My code:

```
headerText.getText().then(function (header) {
                dateTabs.getText().then(function (tab) {

                    h = header.toString().toUpperCase();
                    t = tab.toString();

                    console.log(header, '====', tab);
                    expect(h).toEqual(jasmine.arrayContaining(t));

                });
            });
```

Comment: use for loop to iterate and compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a= [ 'Mon. Dec 10, 2018',
  'Mon. Feb 11, 2019',
  'Tue. Feb 12, 2019',
  'Tue. Aug 13, 2019' ]

var b= [ 'MON. DEC 10', 'MON. FEB 11', 'TUE. FEB 12', 'TUE. AUG 13' ]

// Create new array from array a[]
data: string[] =[];
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
data[i]=a[i].split(',').shift();  // spliting 'data[]=['Mon. Dec 10']'
}

// Validation

expect(data).equals(b);  // To compare the values
```

Hope it helps you